# How do I make a type check function as a while loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, typechecking

```
Ptarget = int(input("What is your target amount of points to achieve?"))
while Ptarget != int:
    print("You have not provided a valid input, please try again.")
    Ptarget = int(input("What is your target amount of points to achieve?"))
```

How do I make it so the while loop functions, by asking the user for another input if the previous was not an integer, without breaking the program?

Answer (score 0):

Use an exception

```
while True:
    try:
        Ptarget = int(input("What is your target amount of points to achieve?"))
        break
    except:
        print("You have not provided a valid input, please try again.")
```